# Ontology based Alexa Skill using Lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, ontology, alexa-skills-kit, owl-api

Is it possible to implement an Alexa Skill in java that imports and reads owl file and execute SPARQL queries? 
I already tried so but I'm facing many problems and library conflicts.

The last result, I implemented it and it executes the query but it is able to retrieve only class values of the ontology not the instances of them!

The following is the maven file pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>smartrecipesF</groupId>
<artifactId>recipes</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>smartrecipesF</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <repositories>
<repository>
  <id>alexa-skills-kit-repo</id>
  <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
</repository>
 </repositories>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.40</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
  <artifactId>alexa-skills-kit</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
<artifactId>org.protege.editor.owl.codegeneration</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
<artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
<version>3.4.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.10</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
<artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
<type>pom</type>
<version>3.0.0</version>
 </dependency>

 </dependencies>




 <build> 
    <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>Launcher</mainClass>
        <systemProperties>
          <systemProperty>


<key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.
disableRequestSignatureCheck</key>

   <value>${disableRequestSignatureCheck}</value>
          </systemProperty>
          <systemProperty>

 <key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.supportedApplicationIds</key>
            <value>${supportedApplicationIds}</value>
          </systemProperty>
          <systemProperty>

<key>com.amazon.speech.speechlet.servlet.timestampTolerance</key>
            <value>${timestampTolerance}</value>
          </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
      </configuration>
       <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>





</project>
```

hope someone helps

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a clear indication of the error you get.

Comment: Owlapi does not currently support SPARQL. We need details of the libraries you're using and the code you've written, or the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Note that there is not, technically, a need to do the heavy lifting in the Lambda function that the skill invokes.  You could start by just exposing an interface to your code's logic elsewhere, at an http endpoint, and make http requests to it from inside the Lambda function to send the request and receive the results, to return to Alexa.  This might be an easier way to at least build your proof of concept.

Comment: [ONT-API](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-api/wiki) is a jena-based OWL-API implementation, it supports SPARQL since jena-arq supports SPARQL. Also in jena there is OWL1 ontology sub-system, see `org.apache.jena.ontology`